# How to remove number from int?

Tags: c#

I got piece of code what adds number(s) to int.

```
int mad = 0; mad++
```

You can increment/add 1 to a number by using the "++" operator. Is there a similar way to subtract/decrement numbers?

Comment: You can also do `mad -= 1;`

Comment: @AmberRose you need to be more clear in regards to how you ask a question. A better question would be `One can increment an Int by using ++` how does one `Decrement an int..?` to say `Remove number from Int` is not proper terminology

Answer (score 6):

The post increment also has an inverse of post decrement:

```
mad--;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following

```
 mad-- ;
```

Be careful, there is a difference between `mad--` and `--mad`.

```
class MainClass5
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double mad;
        mad = 1.5;
        Console.WriteLine(--mad);
        mad = 1.5;
        Console.WriteLine(mad--);
        Console.WriteLine(mad);
    }
}
```

> Output:
>   0.5
>   1.5
>   0.5

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc3z3k8c.aspx